# Remover registros antigos MySQL automaticamente

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela que armazena logs de um sistema. Quero algum método de excluir automaticamente os registros com mais de 60 dias. Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Deseja fazer programaticamente através de uma linguagem ou em SQL?

Comment: Quero fazer diretamente em SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um EVENT com seu intervalor CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY

Abaixo seguem alguns exemplos de criação de "events" no MySQL:

```
CREATE EVENT `Dropar tabela t`
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 DAY
DO DROP TABLE t;
```

Este evento fará com que o MySQL drope a tabela "t" 5 dias a contar do momento da criação do evento.

```
CREATE EVENT O_evento_principal
ON SCHEDULE AT TIMESTAMP '2009-03-10 12:00:00'
DO DROP TABLE t;
```

Este evento fara com que o MySQL drope a tabela "t" no dia 10 de março de 2009 às 12:00h.

> ATENÇÃO:   É importante que, quando um evento é criado com a instrução
>   "EVERY" diante do período, a tarefa será repetida SEMPRE no decorrer
>   de um novo ciclo.

Uma instrução `"EVERY YEAR/MONTH/WEEK/DAY/HOUR/MINUTE/SECOND"` resulta em uma execução continua dentro de um ciclo `ANUAL/MENSAL/SEMANAL/DIÁRIO/HORÀRIO/MINUTOS/SEGUNDOS.`

Por exemplo:

```
CREATE EVENT e
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR
DO DROP TABLE t;
```

Este evento faz com que o MySQL execute um "drop" na tabela "t" a cada ano, considerando como tempo "zero" o momento da criação do evento.

No seu caso você poderia fazer

```
CREATE EVENT `Delete tabela t`
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
Delete FROM tabela
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, SuaData + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,  SuaData , current_date) MONTH , current_date) >= 60;
```

Comment: É exatamente o que preciso, muito obrigada